# Passing data from React frontend to Django Backend

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a completed react app and I have a textarea and button in it and I want the textarea text to be passed to the django backend when the button is pressed. In my folder, I have a React UI, Django project, along with a Django app inside of that project. I know I have to use the django REST framework but I dont know how to pass the text from the React UI to the backend of Django.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for a form, to POST to the backend.  Or, an ajax POST after an `onclick` event.